# How to put a converted date (to a given timezone) in a v-model in order to send such to the backend?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following function to convert a given date and time `scheduled_date`from GMT to a given timezone:

```
toTimeZone: function (time) {
  return moment(time).tz("America/Bogota").format();
},
```

When I display the converted `scheduled_date`in the template I can just use `{{toTimeZone(campaign.scheduled_date)}}`and it works as expected.

However I'm trying to change the input `<md-input type='datetime-local' v-model='campaign.scheduled_date'></md-input>`in order to send the converted `scheduled_date`to the backend but I'm not exactly sure how this should be done.

I tried using [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) in order to do something like `v-model='converted_date`, but that way the date isn't PATCHed to the campaign.

How is this done correctly?

Comment: What is `campaign.scheduled_date`'s type? `Date`? `string`?

Comment: @acdcjunior it's a string

Comment: should be noted that <md-input> is likely https://vuematerial.io/components/datepicker which uses `Date`

Comment: What is the format `campaign.scheduled_date` should have?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call you `toTimeZone` function before sending data to backed.

So your template:

```
<md-input type='datetime-local' v-model='campaign.scheduled_date'></md-input>
```

And your script:

```
...
data() {
  return {
    campaign: {
      scheduled_date: '' 
    }
  }
},
methods: {
 toTimeZone(time) {
   return moment(time).tz("America/Bogota").format();
 },
 sendToAPI() {
   this.campaign.sheduled_date = this.toTimeZone(this.campaign.sheduled_date)
   this.$api.post(this.campaign)
 }
}
...
```